# Continuous Mapping Theorem for Random Variables: Question

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I was wondering about the following proof for the CMT for a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converging in distribution to $X$.

I know this can be made more strict, but assume $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at all points $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

By Portmanteau we have $X_n \Rightarrow X$ (in distribution) if for any open set $O\in \mathbb{R}$

$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb{P_n}[X_n\in O] \geq {P}[X\in O].$$

Now, since for $g$ continuous and $O$ open is the pre-image $g^{-1}(O)$ always open, is it enough to note that

$$\mathbb{P_n}[g(X_n)\in O]= \mathbb{P_n}[X_n\in g^{-1}(O)].$$

Thus

$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb{P_n}[g(X_n)\in O] =\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb{P_n}[X_n\in g^{-1}(O)] \geq P[X\in g^{-1}(O)] = {P}[g(X)\in O]$$

by the above?

Comment: Continuous functions don't map open sets to open sets.

Comment: I think @probtheory misspoke, but the property that the preimages of opens are open is used.